# Web scraping site using polymerjs / webcomponent

Tags: web-scraping, polymer, web-component, go-colly

I'm using [colly](https://github.com/gocolly/colly) to web scrape [youtube charts](https://charts.youtube.com/). This site use polymerjs and as a result, I'm having issues to capture the DOM elements. A simple test I did was `document.querySelector("#search-native")` on console, and it's returning `null`.
I saw an element called `ytmc-app` and I could get this element, but it's not possible to continue querying after that.

Someone has idea how to proceed?